# Why is my Ext.form.FormPanel posting null values?

Tags: null, http-post, sencha-touch

In my [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) application, I've got a `FormPanel` that is supposed to post to my web service.

I've got my FormPanel laid out as follows.

```
var config = {
    // Url for the Web Service - Note that the WebServiceURL MUST end with a trailing "/"
    WebServiceUrl: 'http://webservice.example.com/'
};

function WebService(controller, action) {
    return(config.WebServiceUrl + controller + '/' + action);
};

rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        id: 'loginFormSet',
        title: '',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'emailfield',
                placeHolder: 'Username',
                name: 'Username',
                id: 'Username',
                required: true
            }, {
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                placeHolder: 'Password',
                name: 'Password',
                required: true
            }, {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                id: 'RememberMe',
                name: 'RememberMe',
                label: 'Save login?',
                labelWidth: '40%'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Login',
                ui: 'confirm',
                style: 'margin:2%;',
                handler: function() {
                    doLogin();
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
});


var doLogin = function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: WebService('GetInTouch', 'CommunicateCard'),
        method: 'post',
        params: { UserName: rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues().Username, Password: rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.getValues().Password, RememberMe: Ext.getCmp('RememberMe').isChecked() }
    });
};
```

The problem is that when I press "submit" and watch the post in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)/[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), I don't see any form values. Also, when my web service receives the request, it doesn't receive the form values either.

Here's the HTTP Response from Charles

> > OPTIONS /GetInTouch/CommunicateCard HTTP/1.1
> >     Host: webservice.example.com
> >     Referer: http://192.168.5.206/
> >     Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> >     Origin: http://192.168.5.206
> >     User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/11.0.696.71 Safari/534.24
> >     Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type
> >     Accept: */*
> >     Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
> >     Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
> >     Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

I'm trying to take some of my direction from here
http://mhelpdesk.com/simple-login-form-using-asp-net-mvc-and-sencha-touch/

---

as per Chrixian's answer, I also tried the following code with the same results.

```
rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        id: 'loginFormSet',
        title: '',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'emailfield',
                placeHolder: 'Username',
                name: 'Username',
                id: 'Username',
                required: true
            }, {
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                placeHolder: 'Password',
                name: 'Password',
                required: true
            }, {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                id: 'RememberMe',
                name: 'RememberMe',
                label: 'Save login?',
                labelWidth: '40%'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Login',
                ui: 'confirm',
                style: 'margin:2%;'
            }
        ],
        submit: {
            url: WebService('GetInTouch', 'CommunicateCard'),
            waitMsg: 'submitting',
            success: function(form, response, responseText) {  },
            failure: function(form, response, responseText) {  } 
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP request you pasted isn't POST'ing, it says "OPTIONS" for the HTTP method.

I can see nothing syntax wise that is wrong with your FormPanel and the doLogin function would indeed post the 3 pieces of information you're defining in the params... I don't know what you're returning for the url in `WebService('GetInTouch', 'CommunicateCard')` as you didn't post that function.

Also, while there is nothing wrong with using Ext.Ajax to submit the form, the formpanel provides a shortcut to Ext.Ajax to achieve the same thing ...

```
rpc.views.Contact.CommunicateCard.submit({
   url: 'someurl',
   waitMsg: 'submitting',
   success: function(form, response, responseText) { ... },
   failure: function(form, response, responseText) { ... }
});
```

So you can let it do the heavy lifting of adding the items to the post, etc.

Comment: Ok, It just returns a url.. ya.. as the code sits now it should do what you're expecting it to do.. You can try the .submit() method I added to my answer but you might want to take a look at Fiddler again because as I mentioned you pasted headers for an OPTIONS request not a POST (which is what that Ajax.request would produce) I don't know what would produce the OPTIONS request-- I haven't used Fiddler or Charles so I can't comment on whether that's a result of the proxy or what..

Comment: Yeah, if you look at my edited question, you can see I'm using the `.submit()` function, but it's returning the same results. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: I just pasted your code (original code with the Ext.Ajax.request) into a blank sencha touch app and set the URL to a random page on my box and chrome developer tools shows the request as a POST with the 3 pieces of form data.. so.. ya I don't know what it could be other than the proxy..